# Tokbox php server is not working in aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tokbox

Currently am implementing  a video conferencing application using Tokbox . Sample server and web client is working in my local-host .But when i tried to run the PHP tokbox server on AWS EC2 instance .The server is not working properly.

I am using the following run-demo file to start the server in AWS.

```
export TOKBOX_API_KEY=**********
export TOKBOX_SECRET=**********************

if [ -d "storage" ]
then
  rm -rf storage/
fi

php -S ec2-34-240-136-230.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8083 -t web web/index.php
```

I am geting the alerts `"Server started"  ,Listening on ec2-34-240-136-230.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8083"` after executing the "run-demo" commands. But when i took the URL `http://ec2-34-240-136-230.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8083/room/session` not getting any json result from server.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just do:

```
php -S localhost:8083 -t web web/index.php
```

To confirm it works, after running the above command, open a new SSH session and run:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8083/room/session
```

The issue you're facing is the port is likely being blocked. You will need to expose port 8083 using AWS security groups.